# Roaming around terminals at Dubai intl' Airport(DXB)

Tags: dubai, dxb, airport-terminals, flydubai

I'm flying a flydubai to DXB terminal 2. My flight arrives and leaves from terminal 2. I wanted to ask if I could go around to other terminals since terminal 2 is disappointing... I heard you're restricted etc... That's why I'm asking.

Comment: The important part to note from the linked duplicate is this part from Burhan's answer: `unless you have a boarding pass for Terminal 3 or 1 (gates A, B or C) you cannot freely move between Terminal 2 and Terminal 1`.